# How do I get $(OutDir) programmatically?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm writing a custom build task and and would like to access the value of this property programmatically.  It is possible?  I've looked at all of the members of the Task class and didn't see anything that looked like it would allow me to get the value.

Comment: Can you provide us with a bit more information about how you are writing this task? Which version of MsBuild are you targeting? Are you creating an inline task or are you sub-classing the Task class?

Answer (score 1):

If the custom task can't run without a property, the best practice is to make that property a required input:

```
[Required]
public string OutDir { get; set; }
```

Set by:

```
<MyTask ... OutDir="$(OutDir)" />
```